# Retrieving data from firebase: FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

> I'm building an app which retrieves data from firebase. To display the
>   data in activity and I'm getting an error while I move to the activity
>   which fetch data from firebase.

---

Following are the getter and setter of "People object"

```
public class Person {

//name and address string
private String name;
private String address;

public Person() {
  /*Blank default constructor essential for Firebase*/
}
//Getters and setters
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
```

Java code of main class ..

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText editTextName;
private EditText editTextAddress;
private TextView textViewPersons;
private Button buttonSave;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    buttonSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);
    buttonSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);
    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    editTextAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAddress);

    textViewPersons = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewPersons);

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

    //Click Listener for button
    buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Creating firebase object
            Firebase ref = new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL);

            //Getting values to store
            String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
            String address = editTextAddress.getText().toString().trim();

            //Creating Person object
            Person person = new Person();

            //Adding values
            person.setName(name);
            person.setAddress(address);

            //Storing values to firebase
            ref.child("Person").setValue(person);

            //Value event listener for realtime data update
            ref.child("Person").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        //Getting the data from snapshot
                        Person person = postSnapshot.getValue(Person.class);

                        //Adding it to a string
                        String string = "Name: "+person.getName()+"\nAddress: "+person.getAddress()+"\n\n";

                        //Displaying it on textview
                        textViewPersons.setText(string);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                    System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
                }
            });

        }
    });

}
```

This is the screenshot of my firebase..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yq2S.png)

Crashlog of the app

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.dell.database, PID: 22852
              com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type
                  at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:185)
                  at com.example.dell.database.Main2Activity$1$1.onDataChange(Main2Activity.java:60)
                  at com.firebase.client.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:45)
                  at com.firebase.client.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:45)
                  at com.firebase.client.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:38)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
               Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.example.dell.database.Person] from String value; no single-String constructor/factory method
                  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator._createFromStringFallbacks(StdValueInstantiator.java:428)
                  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromString(StdValueInstantiator.java:299)
                  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromString(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1056)
                  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:136)
                  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:123)
                  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2888)
                  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2034)
                  at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:183)
                  at com.example.dell.database.Main2Activity$1$1.onDataChange(Main2Activity.java:60) 
                  at com.firebase.client.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:45) 
                  at com.firebase.client.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:45) 
                  at com.firebase.client.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:38) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 22852 SIG: 9
Application terminated.

Comment: Please include your crash log in the post.

Comment: in your onDataChange you are already inside the person object you have to read the data directly from the snapShot using getValue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the name and the address please use the following code:

```
ref.child("Person").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    String name = postSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
    String address = postSnapshot.child("address").getValue(String.class);
    String string = "Name: "+name+"\nAddress: "+address+"\n\n";

    //Displaying it on textview
    textViewPersons.setText(string);
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
    System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write the person to the database, you write it as:

```
//Storing values to firebase
ref.child("Person").setValue(person);
```

This writes a single person in the database, as also shown in the screenshot of the console.

When you then read the data, you do:

```
ref.child("Person").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
            Person person = postSnapshot.getValue(Person.class);

            String string = "Name: "+person.getName()+"\nAddress: "+person.getAddress()+"\n\n";

            //Displaying it on textview
            textViewPersons.setText(string);
        }
    }
```

So you **loop** over the children of the `Person` node. Since you've written only a single person to the database, that loop is not needed and in fact breaks the code. To do this correctly, remove the loop:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    Person person = postSnapshot.getValue(Person.class);

    String string = "Name: "+person.getName()+"\nAddress: "+person.getAddress()+"\n\n";

    //Displaying it on textview
    textViewPersons.setText(string);

}
```

By the way, you are using a quite old version of Firebase. I recommend upgrading to a more recent version, even if only because you're more likely to get help. To upgrade, look here: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android